# How To Install Oozie ShareLib File

Tags: hadoop, oozie

how to install oozie shareLib File?

I am Getting Error Like When I am Installing

Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.oozie.tools.OozieSharelibCLI

Comment: http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/12/how-to-use-the-sharelib-in-apache-oozie/. Refer this buddy!!

Comment: I tried Like ./oozie-setup.sh sharelib create -fs FS_URI  http://manithullimilli:11000/user/mani/share/lib/target/oozie-sharelib-4.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the oozie-site.xml there is a property called

```
<property>
        <name>oozie.service.WorkflowAppService.system.libpath</name>
        <value>/user/${user.name}/share/lib</value>
        <description>
            System library path to use for workflow applications.
            This path is added to workflow application if their job properties sets
            the property 'oozie.use.system.libpath' to true.
        </description>
    </property>
```

pls upload the oozie-sharelib- present in the Oozie folder in the below location

```
user/${user.name}/share/lib
```

Comment: <property>
        <name>oozie.service.WorkflowAppService.system.libpath</name>
        <value>/user/mani/share/lib</value>
        <description>
            System library path to use for workflow applications.
            This path is added to workflow application if their job properties sets
            the property 'oozie.use.system.libpath' to true.
        </description>
    </property>  This Is my Propert File Still I am Getting Error

Comment: Dude, 
ensure the location in hdfs '/user/mani/share/lib' if this folder exits?

Comment: The Folder is Their 
drwxr-xr-x   - mani supergroup          0 2015-04-29 14:55 /user/mani/sampleoutput7
drwxr-xr-x   - mani supergroup          0 2015-04-29 14:58 /user/mani/sampleoutput8
drwxr-xr-x   - mani supergroup          0 2015-04-29 15:00 /user/mani/sampleoutput9
drwxr-xr-x   - mani supergroup          0 2015-05-22 15:57 /user/mani/share
drwxr-xr-x   - mani supergroup          0 2015-05-22 12:36 /user/mani/sharelib